# azure blockblob delete fails through SAS URL although it has rw permission? Getting AuthorizationPermissionMismatch response in return

Tags: azure, blob

```
    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(document.AccessURI));
    try
        {
        if (cloudBlob.DeleteIfExists())
            return true;
        }
```

DeleteIfExists returns 403 response, Although SAS URL has rw permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> DeleteIfExists returns 403 response, Although SAS URL has rw
>   permissions.

To delete a blob you need `Delete` permission as well in your SAS. So your permissions should be `rwd`.